# Import file to Isostore WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to copy a song from the windows phone music library to the isolated storage of the app?

I need this to convert each song into wav file format.

**EDIT 1:** I tried this

```
private async void ImportMediaLibrary()
{
    try
    {
        var sourceFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation
            .GetFileAsync("Music/05 Beat It.mp3");
        CopyFileIntoIsoStore(sourceFile);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message+"\n"+e.StackTrace);
    }
}

private async void CopyFileIntoIsoStore(StorageFile sourceFile)
{
    using (var s = await sourceFile.OpenReadAsync())
    using (var dr = new DataReader(s))
    using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using (var targetFile = isoStore.CreateFile(sourceFile.Name))
    {
        var data = new byte[s.Size];
        await dr.LoadAsync((uint)s.Size);
        dr.ReadBytes(data);
        targetFile.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

But I've this error :

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at StretchAndShift.MainPage.<ImportMediaLibrary>d__0.MoveNext()
```

But the file is in the right location... And I would like to import all the file from the Music folder, without giving any path like `"Music/05 Beat It.mp3"`

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far?